# Working with magnifyjs and angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to implement magnify.js in my project. The reference for magnify is 
http://mark-rolich.github.io/Magnifier.js/

I loaded Magnifier JS and Event JS as per documentation and tried to put

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.magnifier();
  }

  magnifier(){
     var evt = new Event(), // throwing error
    let m = new Magnifier(evt); // throwing errror
    m.attach({
    thumb: '#thumb',
    large: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg/400px-Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg',
    largeWrapper: 'preview'
});
```

I get this error

```
Cannot find name 'Magnifier'
```

In my understanding, Magnifier and Event.js are both native javascript classes. In this case, how can i initialize these class

Comment: Are you using the Angular CLI? Or a different seed project?

Comment: angular cli project

Comment: I fixed with another plugin https://thdoan.github.io/magnify/... Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you've included Magnifier and Event sources in your main HTML as described per their documentation, the simplest thing to do is to declare Magnifier and Event in the global scope at the top of your component:

```
var Magnifier;
var Event;
```

Comment: The error notifier (red underline) is gone. But i got this error.   'const' declarations must be initialized in console

Comment: I included it in angular-cli.json

Comment: Let me create a sample project and I'll send you the Git repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Though i fixed it with another plugin, it makes me happy for your efforts to me. Please let me know.